# Clang reports all compiler flags unused when trying to output assembly interleaved with source

Tags: linux, assembly, cmake, x86, clang

I am compiling a project using Clang 16 and CMake. I would like to output interleaved source and assembly to a file.

Within my CMake script I have a line containing my compiler flags:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}  -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -march=native")
```

I added `-S -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel`:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}  -S -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -march=native")
```

However, I cannot see any file generated containing the assembly (and source code)?

Related, I noticed adding `-S -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel` caused these compiler warnings:

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-Wall' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-Wextra' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pedantic' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-march=native' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

It also warned all my include directories and linker inputs were unused.

How can I output the assembly and preferably interleaved with the source?

Comment: What `clang` command did `cmake` run, exactly?  I wonder if something was messed up, like no source files on the command line and thus no use for any compiler options?  Especially since you report it didn't create an output file.  (`ls -clrt` to list by change-time, newest files last.)